# How to verify two int with spaces in c# webdriver selenium test

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have test code to verify if the element value is same as expected

```
var number = Browser.FindElementById("texboxid").GetAttribute("value");
number.ShouldBeSameAs(limit);
//int limit= 50 000
```

I am getting the error. How can I verify with spaces in the number (exact match)

[image]

Comment: ok, now another question: when you compare string to int will you get what you desire?

Comment: Are you sure something like `int limit = 50 000` compiles? So I assume it's just `int limit = 50000`. What happens if the user enters somethin like `5 0000`? Should this also verify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var number = Browser.FindElementById("texboxid").GetAttribute("value");
number.Equals(limit);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.